# C# changing a string to Int or having it as an int

Tags: c#, string, int

Hi i'm trying to add information into an int but i don't know how to declare it as an Int

I am trying to input an age as an int but don't know how.

my code:

```
        Author authorAdd = new Author();
        authorAdd.Name = txtName.Text;
        authorAdd.Age = txtAge.Text;
```

I have tried .Int
I know that it is not .Text that i need but i can't remember what I do need, thanks.

Comment: `int.Parse` `Convert.ToInt32`

Comment: Also, `int.TryParse` (to avoid exceptions)

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
authorAdd.Age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```

If age can be null

Then try like this

```
int age;

if(int.TryParse(txtAge.Text,out age)){
  authorAdd.Age = age;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
authorAdd.Age = int.Parse(txtAge.Text);
```